# MySQL trigger help, capturing a variable from php insert into

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I am writing a MySQL trigger to encrypt a column of sensitive data using RSA plugin. There is an insert statement from the website which is PHP based

```
$sql = "insert into redcap_data (project_id, event_id, record, field_name, value) values 
                            ($project_id, " . getEventId() . ", '" . prep($_GET['id']) . "', '{$_GET['page']}_complete', '2')";
```

In my trigger i need to determine if the project_id and field_name match that of the ProjectID and FieldName from my table redcap_encryption, this is so we only perform the encryption for a particular project.

I'm a little unsure how to intercept and select the project_id and field_name from the insert statement that's passed from website to the DB

Could i just do the following (basic i know)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ssnencrpyt`
BEFORE INSERT ON redcap_data
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF project_id, field_name IN (SELECT ProjectID,FieldName FROM redcap_encryption)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you putting `$_GET` data in your query? Are you hoping you get hacked?

Comment: No idea, it's not our code but i'll pass that on to the provider, thank you.

Comment: If this is commercial software, they just failed a SQL injection audit in the worst possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path:

```
IF (SELECT true FROM redcap_encryption WHERE ProjectID=NEW.project_id AND FieldName=NEW.field_name)....
```